# Match specific word or set of words in a string with regex python

Tags: python

Basically I have a method which parses a XML file and converts the data into a json file depending on some parameters. One of the parameters can be one unique word like **ag** and also **ag & co.**. 
The data in the XML has elements called Firma and each element has an attribute **name**. I need to check for that specific parameter in the name.
I had something like this

```
re.search(r'\b' + rolle + r'\b', name_element)
```

where `rolle` is the parameter and `name_element` ist the word to match against. This works when using for example **ag** in this text: **daimlerchrysler bank ag (zentrale)** or even this one **dimension data germany ag & co.** . But I also need to match **ag & co.** as a `rolle` and that fails when matching against the same example. How could I fix this?

Comment: what is the input string and what's your desired output?

Comment: The input string can be "ag" or "ag & co." I want to compare those 2 strings against other strings like "daimlerchrysler bank ag (zentrale)" and "dimension data germany ag & co." .
For "ag" and "daimlerchrysler bank ag (zentrale)" and also "dimension data germany ag & co." should return a match. 
For "ag & co."  this string "dimension data germany ag & co." should also return a match, but it doesnt with the regex i used above in python `re.search(r'\b' + rolle + r'\b', name_element)` 
`rolle` is the input string, `name_element` is the string to compare against

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to check if the whole word ag or ag & co. is there in the string:

```
check_str="dimension data germany ag & co."

if re.search(r'\bag\b|\bag & co.\b', check_str):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')

True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check whether your input string include a given string you can use `in`:

```
>>> 'ag' in 'dimension data germany ag & co.'
True
>>> 'ag & co.' in 'dimension data germany ag & co.'
True
>>> "ag" in "daimlerchrysler bank ag (zentrale)"
True
>>> "ag & co." in "daimlerchrysler bank ag (zentrale)"
False
```

Comment: this won't work for this use case: 'ag' in 'dimension agile data germany ltd.'

Comment: The problem is I dont want to check if it is in, I want to check the exact string so for example if I search "ag & co." in "sssag & co." this should return no match but if its like this "sss ag & co." this should return match.
I tried using this `re.search(r'\b' + rolle + r'\b', name_element)` but that does not work when the searched string has spaces between

Comment: Maybe adding checks in the beginning and end of the expression works. Does adding `[ ^]` to the beginning and `[ $]` to the end helps? This checks if there's a whitespace or beginning of line before the expression and whitespace or end of line after the expression.